# How to display GIF or MP4

Tags: python, tkinter

I know how to display video in Tkinter, but i don't found videos about a displaying GIF in custom Tkinter.
Please Help.

```
        from PIL import Image
        self.logo = customtkinter.CTkImage(dark_image=Image.open('resources/images/background.gif'),
                                           size=(1282, 720))
        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self, text='', image=self.logo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show an animated GIF, you need to load all the frames from the GIF image and store them as instances of `customtkinter.CTkImage` if you want to use a `customtkinter.CTkLabel` to display the frames.  Then you can use `.after()` loop to show the frames one by one.

Below is an example using a custom `CTkLabel`:

```py
import customtkinter as ctk
from PIL import Image

class GIFLabel(ctk.CTkLabel):
    def __init__(self, master, image_path, **kwargs):
        self._gif_image = Image.open(image_path)
        # set the size of the label to the same as the GIF image
        kwargs.setdefault("width", self._gif_image.width)
        kwargs.setdefault("height", self._gif_image.height)
        # don't show the text initially
        kwargs.setdefault("text", "")
        # delay for the after loop
        self._duration = kwargs.pop("duration", None) or self._gif_image.info["duration"]
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        # load all the frames
        self._frames = []
        for i in range(self._gif_image.n_frames):
            self._gif_image.seek(i)
            self._frames.append(ctk.CTkImage(self._gif_image.copy(), size=(self["width"], self["height"])))
        # start animation
        self._animate()

    def _animate(self, idx=0):
        self.configure(image=self._frames[idx])
        self.after(self._duration, self._animate, (idx+1)%len(self._frames))

app = ctk.CTk()

label = GIFLabel(app, "any.gif")
label.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this on customtkinter but its not object oriented hope it helps:

```
import customtkinter
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image

root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.title("Displaing Gif")

file = "giphy.gif"
info = Image.open(file)

frames = info.n_frames

photoimage_objects = []
for i in range(frames):
    obj = tk.PhotoImage(file=file, format=f"gif -index {i}")
    photoimage_objects.append(obj)


def animation(current_frame=0):
    global loop
    image = photoimage_objects[current_frame]

    gif_label.configure(image=image)
    current_frame = current_frame + 1

    if current_frame == frames:
        current_frame = 0

    loop = root.after(50, lambda: animation(current_frame))

gif_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root, image="", text="")
gif_label.pack()

animation(current_frame=0)

root.mainloop()
```

It's actually importing only one function from tkinter, that allows the user to import pictures from within a gif by their index number.
Reach back if it doesnt work for you!